# Maven artifacts *-classes.jar deployed twice to repository - attachClasses

Tags: java, maven

I have noticed that ***-classes.jars** produced because of attachClasses setting in one certain module inside multi-module maven project deploy twice and since we wanted to change politics to not to deploy releases etc. twice, it needs to be fixed. Problem occur only in module, which is build as war using maven-war-plugin with attachClasses=true and **affect -classes.jar only, other artifacts like sources, poms etc. are deployed only once which is ok**. Double upload happens during maven-deploy-plugin deploy phase. I have taken a look into effective POM, but nothing obvious came to me, no duplicate definitions, goals etc.
Project is pretty complex and intertwined, so I'll list just the interesting bits from POM definitions, I'll be glad if someone has an idea of what could be wrong.

Following command is used for build:

```
mvn -P jboss --batch-mode -U -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -Dorg.xml.sax.driver=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser -pl '!dist' clean package
```

Problem occurs during snapshot or release uploads to repository.

In parent POM, I have among other thigs:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass> <!-- from Spring Boot -->
                            <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                            <Implementation-Build-Time>${maven.build.timestamp}</Implementation-Build-Time>
                            <Jenkins-Build-Number>${build.number}</Jenkins-Build-Number>
                            <Jenkins-Build-Id>${build.id}</Jenkins-Build-Id>
                            <Jenkins-Build-Tag>${build.tag}</Jenkins-Build-Tag>
                            <Jenkins-Git-Commit>${build.git.commit}</Jenkins-Git-Commit>
                            <Jenkins-Git-Branch>${build.git.branch}</Jenkins-Git-Branch>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                    <excludes>
                        <!-- This is where the exclusion occurs -->
                        <exclude>**/aaa.ear</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                    <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
                    <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    <goals>deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- build source artifacts by default -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>cz.bsc.g8.rbcz.onb.web.OnbApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <attach>false</attach>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

In the affected module, I have:

```
    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>for-ear</id>
        <activation>
            <file>
                <exists>pom.xml</exists>
            </file>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>for-ear</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>war</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <configuration>
                                <classifier>ear</classifier>
                                <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/for-ear</webappDirectory>
                                <!-- in ear log4j2 will be places -->
                                <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml</packagingExcludes>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
                        <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

UPDATE:
Added output from build, just a part, where you can see invalid output (row 15 and 27), artifact dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-classes.jar is uploaded twice:

```
02:25:03  [INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) @ dsa-web ---
02:25:03  [INFO] Using alternate deployment repository ACD Snapshot Repository::default::http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots
02:25:03  [INFO] Downloading from ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:03  [INFO] Downloaded from ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 56 kB/s)
02:25:03  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66.war
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66.war (88 MB at 20 MB/s)
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66.pom
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66.pom (15 kB at 672 kB/s)
02:25:07  [INFO] Downloading from ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:07  [INFO] Downloaded from ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/maven-metadata.xml (451 B at 5.8 kB/s)
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 67 kB/s)
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/maven-metadata.xml (451 B at 17 kB/s)
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-classes.jar
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-classes.jar (509 kB at 10 MB/s)
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 85 kB/s)
02:25:07  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-exec.war
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-exec.war (94 MB at 21 MB/s)
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 90 kB/s)
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-sources.jar
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-sources.jar (156 kB at 5.2 MB/s)
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 81 kB/s)
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-classes.jar
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-classes.jar (509 kB at 9.6 MB/s)
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 73 kB/s)
02:25:13  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-ear.war
02:25:17  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/dsa-web-1.3-20201121.012503-66-ear.war (88 MB at 21 MB/s)
02:25:17  [INFO] Uploading to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
02:25:17  [INFO] Uploaded to ACD Snapshot Repository: http://triton.acdlon.com:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/cz/acdlon/b5/lgdn/dsa-web/1.3-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml (1.6 kB at 81 kB/s)
```

Comment: attach a full build output of your build ...

Comment: I have added just a small part, unfortunately I cannot add the full output

Comment: The output shows that the upload is done twice which means there is a wrong configuration in your pom which bind two times the classes generation somewhere ... unfortunately without the full pom's it not possible to say ... furthermore it looks strange with those profiles ` <id>for-ear</id>` which I don't understand for which purpose it is.. ?

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem which was problematic on release builds because redeploy is forbidden in our release artifact store (it is allowed for SNAPSHOTS).

The problem was that in my war project, I was manually packaging the jar because I want to exclude some files from it and I was using attachClasses=true.

Maven is considering that I have created 2 jars to deploy, even if those 2 jars have the same path, name and classifier.

By setting attachClasses to false, I was able to have both my webapp's classes jar and the war deployed but I need to repackage the jar into the war.

The rule seems to be : Each plugin which creates an artifact will register it to be deployed by the deploy plugin.
And there is no deduplication of paths on the deploy plugin which results in multiple deploys of the same artifact.

On the other hand I just stumbled upon one unintended effect of using attachClasses=false which is in my integration testing project for this webapp, I reference the classes jar as a dependency which works fine in maven. But in eclipse, the compile classpath works but the classes from this jar are absent at runtime (NoClassDefFoundError in eclipse when lauchning a junit).

Comment: I had the same problem using a classifier in the war plugin. I solved it using the following configuration:  `<configuration><attachClasses>false</attachClasses></configuration>`